# How to get rid of Ubuntu Pro advertisement when updating apt?

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

Recently, whenever I run `apt update/upgrade`, I get the following message in the terminal:

```
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
```

Does anyone know any way to get rid of this?

Comment: Cannot be seen on my 22.04 system but it certainly looks like one of the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` could be causing this annoyance. General info here: https://ubuntu.com/legal/motd, looks easy enough to disable: "/etc/default/motd-news has an ENABLED=1 setting that if set to 0 will turn off this functionality."

Comment: @JohnC I've not seen it either (inc. on *jammy* [22.04] & *kinetic* [what will be 22.10]) but I'm largely a desktop user, and it depends I gather what ISO/media was used to install the system, plus what packages have been added as to whether or not you'll see it. Only a portion of users see it (*sorry I've not explored the code, nor taken much notice of the discussions over prior weeks-months on those changes; it's of no interest to me; there have been recent announcements on it*)

Comment: Likely of interest - [Ubuntu Pro APT integration is a bit much](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-advantage-tools/+bug/1992026) so the *problem* should reduce with time (*at the very least*) ; though I also noticed it as occurring on Kubuntu or a desktop *flavor* too

Comment: Consider evaluating other DEB based distros?   Debian, Devuan, etc all exist and work.  Voting with your feet might be a reasonable action.  You're not stuck with one distro.

Comment: There is a bug report on this.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-advantage-tools/+bug/1992026

Comment: it is not an "advertisment". it is a "plug". Distinct difference between the 2.

Comment: @Rinzwind It is an advertisement without any doubt. Plugging a commercial product with standard phrasing shown automatically to all people using it IS an ad.

Answer (score 99):

One option is to create a symbolic link for 20apt-esm-hook.conf to /dev/null:

```
sudo ln -s -f /dev/null /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
```

Another option is to just comment out the action lines in that file:

```
sudo sed -i'' -e 's/^\(\s\+\)\([^#]\)/\1# \2/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
```

Or a third option is to just rename that file to a .bak file, and create a zero length file of the same name:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf.bak
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
```

Comment: This seems like the most complete and correct answer to me. Although when using a symbolic link to `/dev/null` I get an notice about it not being a 'regular file'. That third option for the win. Thank you.

Comment: This is the first thing I've tried that really lasted across an `apt update` and reboot.

Comment: I tried the 3rd option (rename the file etc.) and unfortunately it didn't work for me. Ubunut 22.04 LTS server.

Comment: The third option worked great for me on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS desktop. Thanks.

Comment: First option results in `N: Ignoring '20apt-esm-hook.conf' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it is not a regular file` showing app on using `apt`

Comment: Today all pro updates start to be listed in`update-manager` and I hoped messing up the file as described should help there too, which it does not :-/

Comment: Option 3 removed advertisements from command line sudo apt ugrade. However, it did not remove advertisements from GUI Software Updater.

Answer (score 31):

**The apt advert is opt-out**, and Canonical's official way to do so is somewhat of a secret. **The interface for disabling this is:**

`sudo pro config set apt_news=false`

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-advantage-tools/+bug/1950692/comments/16)

Comment: I want to point out a disadvantage to this method -- Ubuntu may add more sources of spam to Ubuntu Advantage in future, and the user would have to set more and more undocumented flags for each spam type as they're added.  However, for users who need Advantage installed, your solution seems like their only option.  As such, I've added this method to the [overall guide on removing spam from Ubuntu](https://github.com/Skyedra/UnspamifyUbuntu) as one method and I thank you for sharing this secret flag with us.

Comment: This does not remove the `Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled` message.

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 25):

Remove message of the day file and disable Ubuntu Advantage:

```
sudo rm /etc/update-motd.d/88-esm-announce
sudo systemctl disable ubuntu-advantage
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question: you got the wrong advert. The question is about a different advert.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 this worked for me

Answer (score 21):

To get rid of the spam, uninstall the program generating the spam.

The package that generates this spam is `ubuntu-advantage-tools`.  Unfortunately removing it is tricky since Ubuntu devs
have decided to make this a required system package so they can make more money
([yes, that is their official justification](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1930914/comments/11)).

A clever person named vi0oss
[came up with a workaround](https://old.reddit.com/r/assholedesign/comments/yg97tk/ubuntu_includes_ads_in_system_update_theyre/iuj7hug/):  replace the spammy package with an additional package which `Provides`, `Breaks` and `Conflicts` with `ubuntu-advantage-tools`.  When this fix broke due to Ubuntu devs requiring a later version, gamemanj found a second [workaround](https://old.reddit.com/r/assholedesign/comments/yg97tk/ubuntu_includes_ads_in_system_update_theyre/jbxyq01/).  All this has been
bundled into the latest version linked below.

## Guide

1. Download the fake package [here](https://github.com/Skyedra/UnspamifyUbuntu/blob/master/fake-ubuntu-advantage-tools/fake-ubuntu-advantage-tools.deb?raw=true).
2. (Optional)  Verify package with `dpkg -I fake-ubuntu-advantage-tools.deb` to check the metadata to see how it works:

```
 new Debian package, version 2.0.
 size 744 bytes: control archive=384 bytes.
     300 bytes,     8 lines      control              
 Package: fake-ubuntu-advantage-tools 
 Version: 0.1
 Architecture: all
 Conflicts: ubuntu-advantage-tools
 Breaks: ubuntu-advantage-tools
 Provides: ubuntu-advantage-tools
 Description: Ban ubuntu-advantage-tools while satisfying ubuntu-minimal dependency
 Maintainer: Vitaly _Vi Shukela
```

3. (Optional) Verify package with `dpkg -c fake-ubuntu-advantage-tools.deb` to check it's actually empty:

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-10-31 11:58 ./
```

4. Install the package:  `apt install ./fake-ubuntu-advantage-tools.deb`

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fake-ubuntu-advantage-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

5. No more ads!

Bonus:  I have uploaded a page with additional ubuntu spam fighting steps on github [here](https://github.com/Skyedra/UnspamifyUbuntu) to get rid of MOTD spam, etc.

Comment: This workaround does not work anymore.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney care to elaborate? It works fine for me.

Comment: I am still using this method myself on 22.10

Comment: Note - there was a request that changed the links to the waybackmachine internet archive.  I have rejected this edit request as the archived version of that page does not allow the user to download the package, thus making the download link not useful.

Comment: It works, but also uninstalls e.g. `gnome-software` and `vanilla-gnome-desktop`, among others. Trying to install them, somehow pulls back in `ubuntu-advantage-tools`.

Comment: @wvengen gamemanj found a new workaround for this, I updated guide with a link to updated package

Answer (score 13):

`strace` says it comes from here:

```
33812 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/messages/apt-pre-invoke-no-packages-apps.tmpl", O_RDONLY) = 3
33812 read(3, "Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free "..., 8191) = 111
```

So:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/messages/*.tmpl
```

Comment: Upon a restart, the message comes back again, so this "fix" is only temporary. Is there anyway to make it more permanent perhaps?

Comment: @Scotty `/var/lib` is for "Variable state information for programs", so there's probably a separate config file elsewhere, maybe in `/etc`. Cf. [How to disable the advertisements when sshing into an Ubuntu machine](/q/1083504/301745)

Comment: Remove those files via /etc/rc.local?

Comment: FWIW, I rebooted my Ubuntu host and those files did not reappear.

Comment: The messages did eventually come back.
Apparently created by `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/messages.py`.
Search for `SS_LEARN_MORE` and change it to `SS_LEARN_MORE = ""`

Comment: Do the same for `TRY_UBUNTU_PRO_BETA`

Comment: So stick the command in crontab ;-)

Comment: @WaxratI I wonder if the message appeared after upgrading a certain package though, such as `ubuntu-advantage-tools` itself.

Comment: Likely an upgrade of that uaclient/messages.py caused the ad to start appearing. After I edited messages.py as described above, the ad stopped appearing

Answer (score 9):

I would just do:

```
apt-get  --assume-yes  --purge  remove  ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

Comment: This appears to be the best answer. When you remove this package, it also removes OTHER branding packages that aren't needed - "ubuntu-advantage-tools* ubuntu-minimal* ubuntu-server* update-manager-core* update-notifier-common*". You can add them back (if needed) without bringing in the tools package.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to install the package ttf-mscorefonts-installer it will pull update-notifier-common and ultimately the ubuntu-advantage-tools. In conclusion there is no way to get rid of the ads with deleting ttf-mscorefonts-installer altogether.

Comment: Why have any other answers been upvoted?! This is the least hacky way to sort out the problem +1

Comment: @moo Thank you. I have tried several methods on > 100 Ubuntu servers and this gave the best results.

Answer (score 6):

You can also raise a complaint at:
https://ubuntu.com/legal/data-privacy/enquiry

The fact there is no easy way to switch off these messages is probably against data protection regulations in many countries.

For instance in the UK, it is illegal to market to any user of a service without asking for prior consent and giving you an opportunity to say no.

Comment: I don’t like it but I don’t think it’s illegal in the U.K. (though I’m no lawyer). It’s not direct marketing as it’s a feature of the system that produces the messages. It’s not targeted; direct marketing (prohibited without consent) would be things like keeping a database of users and emailing them. This is different, and you can opt out by stopping using the os - unlike receiving unsolicited mail. But I agree - complain as it’s not in the spirit of Ubuntu.

Comment: «For instance in the UK, it is illegal to market to any user of a service without asking for prior consent and giving you an opportunity to say no.» <-- I think it's probably not a crime for Ubuntu to inform its existing users that they can get extra support for free that you previously accepted having to pay for.

Comment: It’s the same message for everyone; this has nothing to do with data privacy.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
```

worked for me.  Adding another apt hook that deletes it if it comes back

```
echo '
APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf"}
' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99wupdate-notifier
```