# How to disable this apt warning: OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

Recently when doing and `apt upgrade` apt display this message:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  imagemagick libopenexr25 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
#
# An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
# CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
# Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  cloud-init
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-debian
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 107 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

How can I disable the warning? apt doesn't seem to check the package version, openssl is already updated, also I'm afraid this will be an other message is using to send (r/linux message, Ubuntu Pro message, and now this # messages)

Comment: It's not a warning, it's an information. Just ignore it when you have updated.

Comment: Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/q/1434512/158442?

Comment: @muru That seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Just in case for the community - [apt-news security notification messages may be too vague for users who are not extremely familiar with internal Ubuntu processes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-advantage-tools/+bug/2027929)

Comment: @ManuelJordan I checked the link you posted is this a bug ?

Comment: @JonteYH Yes, it is a bug, it has the `Status` header shown at the top with the _Confirmed_ value