# Remixing Ubuntu 22.04 strange "fail" message at boot about Ubuntu pro

Tags: 22.04

I am remixing an Ubuntu 22.04 as a light Openbox edition (Bento, been there a while at linuxvillage.org) and I am now testing Cubic which seems to work really fine.
In the final ISO testing now in Virtualbox, I get this strange message "failed to start Ubuntu Pro auto attached".

How can I get rid of it?

I also read this thread, [How to get rid of Ubuntu Pro advertisement when updating apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434512/how-to-get-rid-of-ubuntu-pro-advertisement-when-updating-apt) interesting, wanted to comment after answer #12 and couldn't because I need to be seen around here, appearantly. :p

I will try his package (whose built I have explored and examined), to see if it solves it, but I am unsure it is the same process.

Any hints?

Comment: "*...wanted to comment after answer #12...*" The order of answers may change, so it's not clear which answer you might be referring to. Refer to the Share link of each answer instead.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. AskUbuntu uses a Question/Answer format. It's not a threaded discussion forum. You can get the best help if you edit your question to ask a single, clear, answerable question. You don't need to ask for hints -- if your question is clear and answerable, you will get lots of hints.